# Adding text label to each stack of stacked bar in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a stacked bar like this, the gender is display as stack of different color on the stacked bar chart:

[image]

I want to add text to each Stack so that I can know the exact number of male and female for each relation. Below is a section of my data in CSV format:

```
Year,Relations,Female,Male
2002,Family/Relative,0,0
2002,Friend,0,0
2002,Intimate Partner,0,0
2002,Other,0,0
2002,Unknown,1116,0
2003,Family/Relative,0,0
2003,Friend,0,0
2003,Intimate Partner,0,0
2003,Other,0,0
2003,Unknown,364,15
2004,Family/Relative,0,0
2004,Friend,0,0
2004,Intimate Partner,0,0
2004,Other,0,0
2004,Unknown,250,0
```

And below is the code that I believe the text adding code should add to:

```
function update(input, speed) {

       var data = csv.filter(f => f.Year == input)

       data.forEach(function(d) {
         d.total = d3.sum(keys, k => +d[k])
         return d
       })



       yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d3.sum(keys, k => +d[k]))]).nice();

       svg.selectAll(".y-axis").transition().duration(speed)
          .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(null, "s"))

       data.sort(d3.select("#sort").property("checked")
          ? (a, b) => b.total - a.total
          : (a, b) => Relations.indexOf(a.Relations) - Relations.indexOf(b.Relations))

       xScale.domain(data.map(d => d.Relations));

       svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(speed)
          .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSizeOuter(0))

       var group = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
           .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data), d => d.key)

       group.exit().remove()

       group.enter().append("g")
         .classed("layer", true)
         .attr("fill", d => z(d.key));


       var bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
           .data(d => d, e => e.data.Relations);


       bars.exit().remove()

       bars.enter().append("rect")
           .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
           .merge(bars)
       .transition().duration(speed)
           .attr("x", d => xScale(d.data.Relations))
           .attr("y", d => yScale(d[1]))
           .attr("height", d => yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]))
```

below is the link of the active code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6xB2Kzi46hWL37UjlgTs?p=preview

Comment: Well, for most of the years/variables there is simply no space for adding any text, no matter how small the font-size would be. I reckon you should first think about the layout you want, which unfortunately is something we cannot help you with.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Actually I'm thinking about adding an option to transit to grouped bar chart so and also you see I add a "grouped" checked box below. However, I have no idea how to make it.

Comment: So that's a different question. The problem is that is, without a shadow of a doubt, way too broad for S.O.